# How to add OAuth redirect URL to Facebook app config

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am trying to get Facebook authentication on my application using Firebase and i got this prompt. I don't know where to add this URL to.

[image: photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a [Facebook application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register) to use with Firebase. Once your app is created, you need to:

- navigate to the app's developer dashboard
- in the sidebar, click "Add Product"
- select "Facebook Login"
- In the product settings page, enable Client OAuth/Web OAuth login (depending on whether you use Firebase login in a native app or an embedded webview)
- Paste your redirect URL in the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" box.

If everything checks out, your Firebase app should be able to log you in using Facebook. Hope this helps!